# Shower works fine for 5-10 mins then water becomes scalding hot

Tags: shower

I hop in the shower set it to the desired temp; all is fine for 10 mins or so.  Next I hear a drop in water pressure followed by scalding hot water.  I turn the shower head away from me to avoid getting burned.  A couple mins later it returns to the temp I originally set!
What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did someone else in the house flush a toilet or use water in some way?  Is this a new problem or has it alway been that way?  How old is the construction? What type of plumbing material (copper, PEX, etc)

Comment: Sure sounds exactly like the ol' "somebody flushed" problem, barring more details. I wish we had the type of shower valves I've seen in the UK, where you have a knob that sets a temperature (not vaguely H--C, but a specific value like 35 or 40 degrees Celcius) and another knob that controls volume, which actively adjust to mitigate this sort of problem.

Comment: Are there other people in the house when this happens?  Are there machines that automatically use water at a certain time?  Coffeemaker etc.?  If you shower same time every day, this may not be obvious.

Comment: I rent half of a duplex constructed in 1965.  Each unit has its own hot water heater, but we share a common water supply.  My neighbor who lives in the other half of the duplex recently experienced a hot water heater failure.  The maintenance worker had knocked on my door and asked to come in as he thought that the water main shutoff was located in my half of the duplex; upon further inspection he realized it was not.

Comment: No machines automatically use water.  I shower at different times.  I do not know the type of plumbing.

Comment: Sounds like your neighbor is using cold water at the moment and the old pipes just don’t supply enough cold water.  Toilet flush on the other side of the duplex starves your cold water feed.

Comment: I waited until my neighbors left this morning and took a shower; it happened again!  So unless “Claude Raines” (The invisible man) entered their apt when they left no one was home.

Comment: I’d like to thank everyone who has responded to this post thus far!  I’m a former IT professional with 32+ plus years; troubleshooting was one of my specialities.  A plumber I am not nor will I ever be.

Comment: The posts to-date have heightened my awareness and I believe equipped me with knowledge to narrow this one down a bit.  While I am not aware of any automated processes using the cold water I do occasionally hear a water running sound in the same bathroom.  When it occurs it sounds like water running in the toilet though the sound appears to be coming from behind the walls.  Does anyone know of any toilets that periodically cycle?  That would explain the cold water running I hear right?